# Simplifying cube square root

Tags: radicals

I just need some classification on simplifying this cube square root:

$$\sqrt[3]{x^4}$$

Could you cancel the 4 with the 3 and end up with just $x%$

or

would it be $(x^{4})^{1/3}$

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\color{blue}{x^4/x^3}$ and $\color{red}{x^{4/3}}$ are two different things.

$x^{4-3}$ equals $x^4 \cdot {x^{-3}}$, or $\color{blue}{x^4/x^3}$. This is different from $\color{red}{x^{4/3}}$, which is $\sqrt[3]{x^4}$.

Comment: @user5713492 Thanks for catching my mistake — it's fixed.